# How to center GridLayout in Android programmatically (without changing xml file)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

To center a `GridLayout` in its xml file, just add the line

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

or

```
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
```

which can be done for other layouts as well. Likewise, it is simple to center, for example, a `RelativeLayout` programmically: inflate the view, create a new `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` and let it call

```
addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER)
```

before adding it to the view. But unlike RelativeLayout, the method `.addRule` is not defined for `GridLayout.LayoutParams` per the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.LayoutParams.html). How should this be done?

Comment: The premise behind your question is incorrect. `View` layout is done entirely by their parent `ViewGroup` containers, according to their specifications. `LayoutParams` is just a class that can be extended and defined by a `ViewGroup` subclass to contain layout hints by it's children. It can also define custom XML attributes that will be parsed from their children to create the `LayoutParams`. The `android:layout_center*` attributes are defined by `RelativeLayout` to be used as a layout hint by it's children, and it translates into a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` with the relevant rules.

Comment: @corsair992 I understand, it makes sense that its not the GridLayout itself that centers itself but its parent container, as the GridLayout is always centered relative to itself. Nevertheless, I can within the GridLayout in the xml file insert the line `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` and it does what I want, so how would I be able to toggle that line on and off programmatically?

Comment: As I said, the `android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"` just translates to a `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` with a `RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL` rule which is set for the `View`. As I mentioned, the `LayoutParams` of a `View` is just a hint to it's parent on how to do it's layout, and is specified according to the parent.

Comment: @corsair992 Using your comments, I was able to sole this problem, my code is below in an answer. Still, my answer assumes that the containing RelativeLayout only has one child view, the GridLayout. If it contained many children, how would one change the solution so that it only centered the GridLayout and not its other child views?

Comment: Just like the XML layout attributes you use, `LayoutParams` are assigned to the children, _not_ the parent - the parent layouts each child according to it. Your solution seems to be doing the opposite, so I'm not sure how it works.

Comment: @corsair992 Please suggest improvements or write another answer, or suggest how I can change it so looks as it should be.

Comment: Simply, you should be setting the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` on the child (`GridLayout`), instead of the parent (`RelativeLayout`).

Comment: @corsair992 Thanks, does it look correct now? It works as it's supposed to.

Comment: @corsair992: I notice that you have been answering a lot of my questions, much improving my understanding of Android. In case you are interested in more Android questions, I just asked this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25319027/resuming-a-tic-tac-toe-game-in-android-after-closing-the-fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

corsair992's comments helped me understand this problem: it is the parent container that centers its child views, so if your `GridLayout` is for example contained by a `RelativeLayout`, then this problem can be solved by adding this code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams overviewParams =
                    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

RelativeLayout relatLayout = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.relatView); //change to the id of your RelativeLayout.

overviewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_HORIZONTAL); //or CENTER_VERTICAL, or CENTER_IN_PARENT, depending on what you want to do

gridLayout.setLayoutParams(overviewParams); //gridLayout being your GridLayout
```

This is assuming that the parent `RelativeLayout` only contains one child view.

Answer (score -3):

Hi i think this will do what you want:

```
yourLayout.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.CENTER)
```

Comment: Deleted my previous comment. setAlignmentMode is for int, not GridLayout.Alignment, so this method does not work.