# Resuming a Tic-tac-toe game in Android after closing the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm learning Android development by creating a test project: Tic-tac-toe. My Tic-tac-toe app starts with a Main Menu activity with a `Button` that says New Game. After clicking New Game, an activity with a fragment containing a Tic-Tac-Toe game (in a GridLayout) launches. The user can play the game, but when they go back to the Main Menu, the game state is not saved.

I want to change this so that when the user goes back to the Main Menu, they will see a new `Button` called "Continue" (in addition to the "New Game" Button). Once the user clicks "Continue", the game they were playing before continues. If the click the "New Game" button, a new game will be launched like before.

By using the `onSaveInstanceState` method and a `Bundle` `savedInstanceState`, I was able to preserve the game state on orientation changes (by saving the data from the underlying TicTacToe class). My code below shows how I did that. I would like to do something similar this time again - I have read about it, but I don't quite understand the best way to start. Can anyone show me the right steps?

Note that I'm doing this programmatically (i.e. designing the layout outside the xml files)!

My `MainMenu` class:

```
public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void startGame(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainGame.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

with a corresponding xml file `activity_main_game`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/new_game"
        android:onClick="startGame"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now my `MainGame.class` looks like this:

```
public class MainGame extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_game);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new BoardFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_game, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class BoardFragment extends Fragment {

        public TicTacToe t = new TicTacToe();  //A class I wrote that launches a simple TicTacToe game

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                t = new TicTacToe(savedInstanceState.getInt("TicTacToeData"),
                );
            }

    //Graphics stuff here: variable rootView which contains the TicTacToe grid is defined
    //and onClickListeners are added to the ImageViews in the GridLayout which makes corresponding
    //changes to t.

            return rootView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            savedInstanceState.putInt("TicTacToeData", t.getGameData());
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What represents the board state?

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils An int variable represents the board state. So creating a new TicTacToe() results in a clean board, while TicTacToe(2) might represent a board with an x in top center, and so on.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils Nevertheless I would like to see a solution that could be generalized to a more complicated scenario, where the game state is represented by int variables in several arrays for example. But I did not ask for that. I'm working on solving a problem like that at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options

1. `SharedPreferences`: you can use shaerdPreferences to store the state of the game. It would be stored also after the restart of the application.
2. start your game activity with `startActivityForResult()` and implementing `onActivityResult` on your parent activity.

Comment: I've looked into `SharedPreferences`. At which part of the code would I create an instance of SP - in the `onCreateView` method or as an instance variable in the `BoardFragment` class? Also, would implementing that render the `Bundle` method I used for orientation changes unnecessary?

Comment: Also, does going with your first option mean that I need to implement methods like `onPause` and `onResume` in the `BoardFragment` class?

Comment: It's all up to you. You should create an instance of SP in your onCreate method. Then you could update them every time the player does something. `onPause` and `onResume` are not needed.

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to have your `MainGame` Activity return the state of your game when it finishes. Then your `MainMenu` Activity can save that value and use it to start up a game in the same state.

For starters, you will want to start your game Activity in a way that enables it to return a value:

```
public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

    ...

    public void startGame() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainGame.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

Next you will want to make sure that your board Fragment returns the correct state whenever it is closed:

```
public class BoardFragment extends Fragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        Intent result = new Intent();
        result.putExtra("TicTacToeData", t.getGameData());
        getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result);
    }
}
```

Afterwards you will want your menu Activity record the result:

```
public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {
    private int mPreviousGameState;

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            mPreviousGameState = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can pass in this state when you start your game Activity:

```
public class MainMenu extends ActionBarActivity {

    ...

    public void continueGame() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainGame.class);
        intent.putExtra("TicTacToeData", mPreviousGameState);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }
}
```

Now you will need a way to create a board that is already in a specific game state:

```
public class BoardFragment extends Fragment {
    public TicTacToe t = null

    ...

    public BoardFragment (int gameState) {
        t = new TicTacToe(gameState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // recreate the board after an orientation change
            t = new TicTacToe(savedInstanceState.getInt("TicTacToeData"));
        } else if (t == null) {
            // create a new board if this is a new game
            // if this is a continued game, the board is already setup
            t = new TicTacToe();
        }
}
```

And lastly you will need to call the correct version of `BoardFragment` from your game:

```
public class MainGame extends ActionBarActivity {

    ...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_game);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            int gameState = intent.getIntExtra("TicTacToeData", -1);
            if (gameState == -1) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new BoardFragment()).commit();
            } else {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new BoardFragment(gameState)).commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I believe I understand your method and I tried to implement it, but my fragment is static so I cannot implement `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result)` in `onPause`. Can you think of a workaround?

Comment: I think you will want to set the result from inside your Fragment, instead of the Activity. In that case you will use `getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, result)`. I have updated my answer to show this solution.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things you have to do:

1. Get notified within Main class when your MainGame Activity is closed
2. Update the UI to change the button text

***To get notified within Main class:***

You can start `MainGame` Activity using `startActivityForResult` instead of `startActivity`. Then override the `onActivityResult` method on Main class to be notified when the user close the `MainGame`.

Also you will have to modify `MainGame` to invoke `setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)` or `setResult(int resultCode)` method when the user click the back button (depending on whether you want to pass additional data back to the Activity.

Override the onBackPressed() method in your `MainGame` class to invoke the setResult method. E.g.

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    super.onBackPressed(); // otherwise your Activity won't be closed
}
```

Have a look at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#StartingActivities for a more detailed example

***To Update the UI:***

1. Save the button as a local variable (in your onCreate method)
2. Update the Button text `MainGame` Activity

   ```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Update the button text to "Continue"
            } else {
                // Change the button text back to "New Game"
            }
        }
    }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to redesign your app to have only a single `Activity` (or `ActionBarActivity`) subclass and multiple `Fragment` subclasses for each screen you want to show. You can keep a reference to both fragments in your `Activity`. This will implicitly retain the state of the fragment which displays the game board.

Comment: @Sid One caveat: this solution only retains the state of the game as long as your app is running. As soon as the system destroys the activity, the state will be lost unless you use some more persistent storage method.