# Is having a managed static reference to a Fragment or Activity ok?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, memory-leaks

I was wondering if having a managed static reference to a `Fragment` or `Activity` is ok? By managed I mean releasing the static reference on the relevant lifecycle callback. Consider the following code please:

```
public class StaticReferencedFragment extends Fragment {

    public static StaticReferencedFragment instance;

    public StaticReferencedFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_static_referenced, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        instance = this;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        instance = null;
    }
}
```

Do I run the risk of leaking the `Fragment/Activity` object?

Comment: no it is not. It smells always like bad design

Comment: Why would you ever need this

Comment: @Blackbelt For the sake of curiosity, elaborate on the matter. Why is it a bad idea?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I'm just asking. Some times it's convenient to be able to just access the damn thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Do I run the risk of leaking the Fragment/Activity object?

Yes. For example, an unhandled exception while your fragment is visible will bypass your lifecycle methods and cause you to fail to `null` out the `static` field.

Beyond that, it's unclear what this buys you:

- An activity hosting this fragment can simply hold onto the fragment in a regular field
- Other fragments in the activity should neither know nor care that this fragment exists (fragments should worry about themselves and their activity, not peer fragments)
- Other components, like services, and other threads should neither know nor care that this entire *activity* exists, let alone this fragment (use an event bus or other loosely-coupled modes of communication)

Comment: Actually I was reading your old answer. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25344959/using-the-static-keyword-to-preserve-the-state-of-a-tic-tac-toe-board-in-android